# Create std::string inside debugger

Tags: c++, windbg

I'm debugging a x86 program (written in C++ / VS2012 / statically linked) in WinDbg and I have its object files. My point of interest is this function:

```
static bool isValidToken(const std::string& token)
```

This function receives a string token to validate a client.

I want to be able to test it inside the debugger, but to do so I would have to create an `std::string` so I could do the command: `.call isValidToken(<addr_of_string>)`.

Dumping and manipulating `std::string` inside WinDbg is relatively easy, but is it possible to create it?

I'm able to hijack other strings and change it so I can test, but it obviously crashes the program sometimes. I'm trying to find a static constructor for the class but it's really hard because it's heavily based on templates.

Comment: Is there the ability to create objects in WinDbg?  I doubt it.  Doesn't matter if it's `std::string` or your own user objects.

Comment: You could inject some ASM code (after allocating enough space) to create a new `std::string` object.

Comment: @cdonts that's the point: How to create it?

Comment: Write the code in C++ and see the resulting assembly. Another option (probably easier) would be to create a global `string` object in a DLL and inject it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By debugging a test program in Visual Studio (suggested by [@cdonts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2116607/cdonts) in the comments) I could find the constructor prototype for `std::string`. It is shown in the command that follows.

Back to WinDbg I issued the following command to find symbols with that signature (note that `*` is used as wildcard to replace spaces):

```
0:047> x Manager!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>*>::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>*>
```

Found the following constructors:

```
6e36bf96 Manager!std::basic_string<...PROTOTYPE...> (char *, char *)
6e67fa65 Manager!std::basic_string<...PROTOTYPE...> (class std::basic_string<...PROTOTYPE...> *, int, int)
6d519218 Manager!std::basic_string<...PROTOTYPE...> (class std::_String_const_iterator<...PROTOTYPE...>)
6d54c745 Manager!std::basic_string<...PROTOTYPE...> (char *, unsigned int)
6d0c2666 Manager!std::basic_string<...PROTOTYPE...> (char *)
6d1f2a43 Manager!std::basic_string<...PROTOTYPE...> (class std::basic_string<...PROTOTYPE...> *)
6d151eb8 Manager!std::basic_string<...PROTOTYPE...> (class std::basic_string<...PROTOTYPE...> *)
```

I ommited some parts of the prototypes, but the one that interests us is:

```
6d0c2666 Manager!std::basic_string<...PROTOTYPE...> (char *)
```

This one only takes a `char *` as argument. It is used to initialize the newly created string, and it's really easy to provide. So, the steps to do the job are:

1. Allocate memory for the object ( `std::string` ). We use 1000 because it's the minimum allocation size:

   ```
   0:047> .dvalloc 1000
   Allocated 1000 bytes starting at 03fe0000
   ```
2. Allocate a buffer for the `char *` parameter:

   ```
   0:047> .dvalloc 1000
   Allocated 1000 bytes starting at 03ff0000
   ```

   We can initialize the buffer with:

   ```
   0:047> ea 0x03ff0000 "my string here"
   ```
3. Place a `.call` command passing two parameters: The first one is the address of the memory we allocated for the object itself, that actually happens to be a `this` argument, because the funcion uses `thiscall` calling convention (WinDbg knows it and places it in `ecx`). The second one is the `char *` parameter for the constructor:

   ```
   0:048> .call 6d0c2666(0x03fe0000, 0x03ff0000)
   Thread is set up for call, 'g' will execute.
   WARNING: This can have serious side-effects,
   including deadlocks and corruption of the debuggee.

   0:048> g
   ```

After that we have a good `std::string` object (at `0x03fe0000`) to work with, containing the text `"my string here"`.